# jquery how to stop settimeout from looping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want after my page loads to do a trigger click once and only once. 
many posts swear that settimeout only fires once, but in my case it is infinite!
here is one of my many trials.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#btn1").trigger('click');
    },1000);
});
```

I have tried moving that into a function outside the document.ready and then add cleartimeout, but then it stops from firing at all:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    test();
});
function test() {
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
        $("#btn1").first().trigger('click');
    },1000);
    clearTimeout(t);
}
```

What am I doing wrong!?

Comment: setTimeout runs only once, but trigger click might have the problem...

Comment: The looping behavior may hinge on what happens when you click. If it's a link pointing to the same page, your page will refresh and start everything all over again.

Comment: or if the click triggers test.. odnt use interval to run something once.

Answer (score 1):

use clearTimeout() inside the setTimeout().It clears the timeout after triggering the click

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 test();
});
function test() {
  var t = setTimeout(function() {
  $("#btn1").trigger('click');
  clearTimeout(t);
 }, 1000);
}
$("#btn1").on('click',function(){
 console.log("Clicked");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6G4pR/

Answer (score 0):

use `e.stopPropagation()`, this might be because of event bubbling.

**HTML**

```
<button id="btn1">my button</button>
```

**JS**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#btn1").trigger('click');
    },1000);

  $("#btn1").click(function(e){
    console.log('clicked');
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(e);
  })
});
```

[CODE](http://codepen.io/raunay/pen/vjgqe)